# CSS formatter Google uses for Gmail and other products?

Tags: css

What CSS formatter does Google use for products like Gmail?  Is it public?

Closure compiler only support CSS minification from my understanding.

Background: I'm looking for a CSS3 formatter and thought Google might be a good start as CSS Tidy doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look here? http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=css3&projectsearch=Search+projects

Comment: @ThomasBerger, no luck.  Did you see anything?  Having a _.any(members, function(m) { m.email.endsWith("google.com")}) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what they use. You can try online [tabifier](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier). For my projects, I use Ctrl+ K,Ctrl+D shortcut in [Visual Studio 2012 Express for web](http://microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-web) (free) in CSS / JS /HTML files and it does the document formatting. Besides, it shows the intellisense and the code snippet for CSS properties with standard and vendor-prefixed rules and [much more](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6).

Example input:

```css
div.tree{background-color:lime}div.tree>div.node{line-height:2px}div.tree>div.node:first-child{margin-top:13px}div.tree>div.node li:before{content:"-->"}p#copyright{line-height:15px}
```

Output (Ctrl+k,Ctrl+d):

```css
div.tree {
    background-color: lime;
}

    div.tree > div.node {
        line-height: 2px;
    }

        div.tree > div.node:first-child {
            margin-top: 13px;
        }

        div.tree > div.node li:before {
            content: "-->";
        }

p#copyright {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I'm working in Eclipse.  A great solution would be a hosted solution that would work with Eclipse or Visual Studio.  However, I don't think Visual Studio 2012 lets you write a formatter for CSS. : (

Comment: @joshunger, I have updated the answer with sample I/O. Its true that the solution is not cross-IDE. The portable solution would be an online service such as tabifier or a stand-alone application.

Comment: Sorry, the answer to this question should answer "What CSS formatter Google uses?", thanks for the screenshots.